# HP P410i Array Controller and lost logical Drive

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, data-recovery

Today earlier we lost the logical drive information for a 4 drive raid array that was array B!

The system had two arrays A and B A being the single system drive and B the Data drive of 4 x 136Gb drives giveing a raid of 1 x drive of approx 250Gb.

After adding 1 x additional drive to the drive cage to make 6 drives in total the ACU reported 1 x unallocated drive and the two other arrays!

But when we came to look across the network at files on the Array B the folders were there but no files!

HP got us to update the ACU software and also the Array Controller Firmware which we did and now we get a report of 1 x Array A (system drive) and 4 unallocated devices!

Is there a way to scan these 4 devices and rebuild the Array B configuration??

This can be HP or 3rd party  Any help please..

Answer (score 4):

HP ProLiant Smart Array RAID technology stores the array information on the actual drives and *not* on the controller. Disk drive position within the cage is EXTREMELY important.

- Turn the server off.
- Remove the power cables from the system.
- Remove the drives and place them back in the original drive order. I don't know if disks were moved, but go back to the original setup.
- Do not insert the 6th drive that you added after the fact.
- Reinsert the power cables and power the machine on.
- Watch the POST and boot process. If prompted by the Array BIOS utility, ensure the arrays are enabled and *not* disabled (often need to press "F2").
- See if the system boots and both arrays show up.

Please report back with what happens.

May I ask what you were trying to do by inserting the new drive? Please provide more detail.